# How to compare more than 3 array to find the one with highest priority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, bubble-sort

I have following array set holding priorities,

```
array1 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
array2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
      |
      |
      |
arrayn = [1, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to find out easiest way to find out the array variable which having highest priority i.e 1

It should check in a following way,

If last element of any array is lowest that should be return.
If last element of more than one array is same then previous element of that array should be matched
In above given example last 3 values of all the 3 array are same so it will check for the 2nd last element

```
array1 = 2
array2 = 1
array3 = 3
```

So it should return array2.

Please let me know if any one fail to understand the question

More Examples

Example 1

```
arr1 = [1,1,1,1,3]
arr2 = [3,3,3,3,2]
should return arr2
```

Example 2

```
arr1 = [2,2,2,1,3]
arr2 = [1,2,1,3,3]
should return arr1, as arr1.last == arr2.last (i.e. 3) 
but arr1[3] < arr2[3] i.e. (1 < 3)
```

Comment: I'd like to tackle on that problem but I don't understand the question :(

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the questions. Can you present more examples? It seems like there are two main reasons to missunderstand: First 'highest' priority means 'lowest' or 'left-most'? And: Does 'last' element mean 'left-most' or 'right-most'?

Comment: Should arrays be in equal size?

Comment: Array always be of equal size, 1 is highest priority followed by 2, 3, 4...... & last element means array.last

Answer (score 3):

For equal sized arrays (and if I understand the question right) this should work:

```
arrays = [
  [1, 2, 1, 1, 3],
  [1, 3, 1, 2, 3],
  [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
  [1, 3, 1, 1, 3]
]

p arrays[arrays.transpose.reverse.map{|el|
  next if el.count(el.min) != 1
  el.rindex(el.min)
}.compact[0]]
```

Result:

```
#=> [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Step by step: Transpose arrays and start to check from last chunk. If there is not one minimal priority skip this chunk (put nil in output), if only one - get it's index. Remove all nil elements and use first found index to print desired array.

*UPDATED*

If you wish to handle the case when initial array of arrays doesn't have answer you could change the code in this way:

```
idx = arrays.transpose.reverse.map{|el|
  next if el.count(el.min) != 1
  el.rindex(el.min)
}.compact[0]

p idx ? arrays[idx] : "no answer"
```

The result for `[[1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,2], [2,1,1,1,1], [2,1,1,1,2]]` will be:

```
#=> "no answer"
```

Comment: In your example i want this answer `[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]` , and Array will be always of the same size

Comment: arr1 = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3], arr3 = [1, 3, 1, 1, 3]. They both have `1` in [3] position. Why arr1 is a right answer?

Comment: your answer will fail for 
`[[1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,2], [2,1,1,1,1], [2,1,1,1,2]]`

Comment: It's because in this case there we don't have answer. I could update answer with example of how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
tab = [array1, array2, array3, arrayn]
i   = -1
while tab.count != 1 && tab.count + i >= 0
    tab = tab.select { |t| t[i] == tab.map { |j| j[i] }.min }
    i   = i - 1
end
result = tab[0]
```